# Python for loop not iterating for i=1,2 only outputting first iteration

Tags: python, loops

I am building a for loop using Euler's method for differential equations. The for loop however is not incrementing and only displaying the values for i=0 and not i=1 or i=2.

I have tried manually assigning all arguments and reconstructed the for loop.

```
import math

def Euler(a,b,N,alpha):
    h=(b-a)/N
    t=a
    w=alpha

    for i in range (0,N):
        w=w+h*(math.exp(t-w))
        t=a+(i*h)
        return t,w    
Euler(0,1,2,1)
```

I expect the function to return results for i=1 and i=2

Comment: your `return` is inside the `for` loop. (did you meant to put `print` there instead?)

Comment: What's the result you expected?

Comment: `return` exits the function immediately, so your loop only executes once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pault mentioned in the comments, your return is inside the loop, which means the function exits on the first iteration.

What you probably want is `yield`, which would turn the function into a generator:

```py
import math

def Euler(a,b,N,alpha):
    h=(b-a)/N
    t=a
    w=alpha

    for i in range (0,N):
        w=w+h*(math.exp(t-w))
        t=a+(i*h)
        yield t,w

for x, y in Euler(0,1,2,1):
    print(x, y)

>>> 0.0 1.1839397205857212
>>> 0.5 1.3369749844848988
```

Comment: What exactly does x,y represent in the second for loop?

Comment: @BickenBackBeingBoolean The Euler function/generator yields a tuple (`yield t, w`). Doing the `for x, y in ...` unpacks the tuple into two loop variables, instead of having to index a single loop variable (like `x[0]` or `x[1]`).

Answer (score 0):

Your return is in the `for` loop. Unindent `return` once.